# Array from Firebase won't append

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have got my code to work recently, but I changed my code a lot and now I don't understand why but now my array fetched from firebase is printing, but is not appended to the UITableView. It has worked before, but I don't know what is wrong. Furthermore, when it was working, it was also duplicating. Here is my current code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var nearbyTableView: UITableView!
var myList: [String] = []
var handle:DatabaseHandle?
var ref:DatabaseReference?
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellName
    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]



    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home2") as! ShopViewController
    viewController.name = cellName
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    print("row\(indexPath.row)")
    print("name: \(cellName)")
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            determineMyCurrentLocation()
}

func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child("shops")

    messageDB.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let text = snapshotValue["name"] as! String

        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation



        self.myList.append(text)
    })

    self.nearbyTableView.reloadData()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
{
    print("Error \(error)")
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: [Related](https://pics.me.me/my-code-doesnvt-work-have-no-idea-why-my-code-14032928.png). | Try to make this a [mcve], please! <3

Comment: you are reloading tableView before the messageDB.observe Handler is Called, Try using dispatch group and reload tableView , try dequeuing with Breakpoints

Comment: Can do two Options either reload table when a new entry is appended by just writing reload tableView just after appending text or by using dispatch group that will execute reload TableView command only when all Data from Handler is Appended

Comment: use dispatch main thread on tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change you `didUpdateLocations` as follows, not 100% sure, but it could help you

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child("shops")

    messageDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let text = snapshotValue["name"] as! String

        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        self.myList.append(text)
        self.nearbyTableView.reloadData()

    })

}
```